# Proving every group of order 2673 has a non-trivial proper normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

If $|G|=2673=3^511$ then let $S \in Syl_3(G)$. Then the number of conjugates of $S$, $n_s \equiv 1$ mod $3$ and $n_s | 11$. But the only divisors of 11 are 1 and 11, and therefore $n_s=1$ so the $S$ is the unique sylow-3 subgroup of G and hence is normal. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Actually there are $68$ groups of order $2673$, among which $67$ of them are $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(2673,n)=\operatorname{SmallGroup}(243,n)\times C_{11}$ for $n=1,\cdots,67$ (that is, $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(243,n)$ runs through all groups of order $243$). The remaining one is $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(2673,68)=C_3^5\rtimes C_{11}$.